# Nested VBA inline function

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a "GPT Fill" function that works as follows.

1. User defines a reference range of two columns containing prompts and completions
2. User then provides set of additional prompts that he/she wants to complete
3. User calls GPTFill(TrainingRange, FillRange) with the properly selected training pairs and the range that contains the items to be completed
4. Macro iterates through examples and creates a string of "prompt/completion" pairs
5. Macro then amends prompt with additional examples it wants GPT to complete.
6. Macro submits prompt to GPT asking for return-delimited answers
7. Macro splits answers into array and attempts to fill cells right next to FillRange.

See below for visual

[image]

The issue I am encountering is that the population of the first item works just fine, but when I try to loop through the remaining items I seem to retrigger the GPTFill function even though I have disabled events and autocalculation. Anybody have any ideas as to what's wrong with my code?

```
Function GPTFill(TrainingRange As Range, FillRange As Range) As String
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False

'Create compounded prompt from Training Range
strPrompt = "I'll give you a few examples of prompts and completions. "

'Iterate through training range to collect examples into prompt
For Each trainingRow In TrainingRange.Rows
 strPrompt = strPrompt & "Prompt: " & trainingRow.Cells(1, 1).Value & vbCrLf & "Completion: " & trainingRow.Cells(1, 2).Value & vbCrLf
Next trainingRow

'Concatenate all prompt completions into a single input to see if we can get efficiency gains
strPrompt = strPrompt & vbCrLf & "Now complete the following items given the pattern above. Return just the completion but not the input prompt" & _
                                 "text and separate the text with line returns: " & vbCrLf
For Each fillRow In FillRange.Rows
 strPrompt = strPrompt & fillRow.Cells(1, 1).Value & vbCrLf
Next fillRow

outString = GPT(strPrompt)
'Split into array
GPTOutArray = Split(outString, vbCrLf)


'Populate the other cells
Call PopulateRange(FillRange, GPTOutArray, 1)
GPTFill = GPTOutArray(0)
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Function


End Function

Function PopulateRange(tmpRange As Range, tmpArray, intOffset As Integer)

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
For i = 1 To UBound(tmpArray)
  tmpRange.Cells(i + 1, 1).Offset(0, intOffset).Value = tmpArray(i)
Next i

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Function
```

I have tried setting application.calculation to manual and application.enableevents to false, but any attempt to loop through the values and populate the remaining items that need to be filled re-trigger the original GPTFill macro

Comment: What does ```outString = GPT(strPrompt)``` do? Where is ```GPT()``` defined?

Comment: Functions called from a worksheet cell are restricted in what they can do - for example they can't change `Application.Calculation`, and they can't write values to a worksheet (other than returning a value or array of values as their return value)  See - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel-f2f0ce5d-8ea5-6ce7-fddc-79d36192b7a1

Comment: I figured it out...instead of trying to separately populate the range underneath the calling cell I just return the transposed array like 
`
outString = GPT(strPrompt)
'Split into array
GPTOutArray = Split(outString, vbCrLf)

'Populate the cells with return values
 GPTFill = Application.Transpose(GPTOutArray)
`

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out...full solution is below including the GPT API calling function.
Note that the spreadsheet has corresponding ranges for the API key and the temperature setting on a tab called "Config". You will need to create named ranges for these two values and obtain an API key from OpenAI for the calling MSXML2.XMLHTTP request to function properly.

```
Function GPT(strInPrompt)
  
  Dim request As Object
  Dim text, response, API, api_key, DisplayText, GPTModel As String
  Dim GPTTemp As Double
  Dim startPos As Long
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim httpRequest As Object

  
  'On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
  'API Info
  API = "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions"
  api_key = Trim(Range("API_Key").Value)
  GPTModel = "gpt-3.5-turbo"
  

  If api_key = "" Then
    MsgBox "Error: API cannot be blank! Please go to 'Config' tab and enter a valid OpenAI API key", vbExclamation, "Excel for ChatGPT"
    Exit Function
  End If
    
  'Clean input text and make JSON safe
  text = CleanInput(strInPrompt)
  
  'Create request object
  Set httpRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

  GPTTemp = Range("GPT_temperature").Value
  
  
  Dim requestBody As String

  requestBody = "{" & _
              """model"": """ & GPTModel & """," & _
              """temperature"": " & GPTTemp & "," & _
              """messages"": [{""content"":""" & text & """,""role"":""user""}]" & _
              "}"

  With httpRequest
     .Open "POST", API, False
     .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
     .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & api_key
     .send (requestBody)
  End With

  
 ' Open and send the HTTP request
  If httpRequest.Status = 200 Then 'Successfully called OpenAI API

   response = httpRequest.responsetext

    'Extract content
    Result = Split(response, """,""")
    For i = LBound(Result) To UBound(Result)
      If InStr(Result(i), "content") > 0 Then
            startPos = i
            Exit For
      End If
    Next i
  
    DisplayText = Mid(Result(startPos), InStr(Result(startPos), ":") + 2, InStr(Result(startPos), """},"))
    DisplayText = Mid(DisplayText, 1, InStr(DisplayText, """},") - 1)
  
    DisplayText = Replace(DisplayText, "\n", vbCrLf)
    Set request = Nothing
    GPT = DisplayText
   Exit Function
  Else 'something went wrong with OpenAI call
    MsgBox "Request failed with status " & httpRequest.Status & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Error:" & vbCrLf & httpRequest.responsetext, vbCritical, "OpenAI API Request Failed"
  End If
  
  Exit Function
  
End Function

Function CleanInput(strProcess)
  strProcess = Replace(strProcess, Chr(34), Chr(39))
  strProcess = Replace(strProcess, "/", " ")
  strProcess = Replace(strProcess, "\", " ")
  strProcess = Replace(strProcess, vbCrLf, "\n")
  strProcess = Replace(strProcess, vbLf, "\n")
  strProcess = Replace(strProcess, vbCr, "\n")
  strProcess = Replace(strProcess, vbTab, "\t")
  CleanInput = strProcess
End Function


Function GPTFill(TrainingRange As Range, FillRange As Range) As Variant

'Create compounded prompt from Training Range
strPrompt = "I'll give you a few examples of prompts and completions. "

'Iterate through training range to collect examples into prompt
For Each trainingRow In TrainingRange.Rows
  strPrompt = strPrompt & "User: " & trainingRow.Cells(1, 1).Value & vbCrLf & "System: " & trainingRow.Cells(1, 2).Value & vbCrLf
Next trainingRow

'Concatenate all prompt completions into a single input to see if we can get efficiency gains
strPrompt = strPrompt & vbCrLf & "Repeat for the following rows. Return only the completion portion of the text separated by paragraph returns: " & vbCrLf
For Each fillRow In FillRange.Rows
 strPrompt = strPrompt & fillRow.Cells(1, 1).Value & vbCrLf
Next fillRow

outString = GPT(strPrompt)
'Split into array
GPTOutArray = Split(outString, vbCrLf)

'Populate the cells with return values
 GPTFill = Application.Transpose(GPTOutArray)

End Function
```